# Running a local Yii2 server with WAMP

Tags: php, mysql, api, yii, yii2

I am a frontend JS dev and I've begun working on a project that has a PHP backend running with Yii2 framework. The project came with no setup instructions so I'm trying to figure it out as I go, but coming from Node.js... it's pretty confusing.

I downloaded and installed WAMP, created the MySQL DB for the API using MyPHPAdmin, and imported the data from a dump. That worked and I can see the tables and data. Now when I go to `localhost` I see that WAMP is running. I tried the sample Yii project and that also runs at `localhost/yii-test/web`.

According to Yii I am to serve this API by moving this entire API directory to the `/www` directory of the WAMP install. Now if I go to `localhost/fania-api` I see the directory listing for my server. To me this says that the API is accessible locally.

I have configured the `.env` of my frontend to point to `localhost/fania-api`, but when I send any request I get a CORS error, which I am assuming is masking some 404 or 500 error. Now the funny thing is the .env I was given comes with the URL `http://fanintelligence.localhost`, not the Yii given `localhost/fania-api`.

So my question is how do these two things fit together? I installed WAMP and setup the MySQL DB at the default port, but how does my API know it's there? How can I know if it's the right port? And what about these two different URLs, how do they match up?

Also the API does not contain a /web folder, not sure if that is an issue or not but I couldn't serve it with `php yii serve` either. If this was a Node.js server I'd clone, `npm install` and `npm run start` which would probably do something like `build` and `serve`. I can't believe this is so difficult to setup in comparison.

Any advice or help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: When I try to reach my server from the frontend at either address I get:
`Access to fetch at 'http://localhost/fania-api/oauth2/token?accessToken=undefined' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
/fania-api/oauth2/token?accessToken=undefined:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED`
However I do not believe this is an actual CORS error as the previous developer also used the local to test, so the CORS policy will allow for this. My guess is the address I'm pointing to is incorrect or the server is not actually live.

If I try to run `php yii serve`:
`Document root "C:\Users\hesel\dev\repo\eartotheground\fania-api\console/web" doe
s not exist.`

But the crux of the erroneous behaviour is the inability to connect to a supposedly live local server (is it even live? how can I tell?).

Comment: P.S. if I cannot get this running locally I will have to just push and test on live, but I really, REALLY, don't want to do that...

Comment: can you give us the error?

Comment: See edit at bottom (too long for comments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. For hosting with WAMP:

1. Place entire server code folder in `www/` (in WAMP install dir)
2. Edit `wamp64\bin\apache\apache{version}\conf\httpd.conf`:

```
DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/{your project}/{optional public folder}"
<Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/{your project}/{optional public folder}">
```

3. Edit `wamp64\bin\apache\apache{version}\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost {project name}:80>
 ServerName {project name}.localhost
 ServerAlias {project name}.localhost
 DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/{your project}/{optional pub"
 <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
   Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
   AllowOverride All
   Require local
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Your server should now be live at `{project name}.localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

- If yii is installed via composer, go to the project,open the terminal and run `./yii serve`
- If yii has been downloaded as an archive file:
  open terminal/cmd prompt in the folder of the project and 
  type `composer install` to ensure all packages in vendor are installed.

got to config/web.php

`'request' => [
        'cookieValidationKey' => 'put your random generated string',
],`

Access the application via http://localhost/basic/web/

*NB: try xammp  for php local development you wont regret*

Comment: It is installed via composer. So:
`$ ./yii serve
Document root "C:\Users\hesel\dev\repo\eartotheground\fania-api\console/web" does not exist.`
There is no `config/web.php` or even a `config` directory.

Comment: Root dir contains the following directories: `./.ebextensions, ./api, ./common, ./console, ./environments, ./public_html`

Comment: go to the root folder where there is `yii` file add run the command `php yii init`